# Delaying and iterating an object with rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I am trying to loop through the keys in an object and iterate over them after a set interval between one key to another. 
I am trying to achieve this using the interval operator but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

```
let obj = { 'a': [1,23,3], 'b': [12,23,2] };
 for(let key in data) {
      Observable.interval(5000).subscribe( () => {
         // perform operation with data[key]      
       });
  }
```

I don't see any delay between my loops and all i am getting is a sudden iteration which is not different from the normal loop beahvior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're creating a new Observable in each iteration.

I guess you wanted to make something like this:

```
Observable.from(Object.keys(obj))
    .concatMap(item => Observable.of(item).delay(5000))
    .subscribe(item => console.log(item));
```

The actual delay is performed by `concatMap` that waits until each inner Observable completes before subscribing to the next one.

Comment: Is it possible to delay from the second iteration onwards, meaning execute the first iteration and then delay the rest. something like timer does

Comment: @Bazinga777 The callback to `concatMap` takes as an optional argument an index so you could write `.concatMap((item, i) => i === 0 ? Observable.of(item) :
 Observable.of(item).delay(5000))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip and timer operators. Timer is like interval with with arg 0 - will start emitting immediately.

```
let obj = { 'a': [1,23,3], 'b': [12,23,2] };

Rx.Observable.zip(
   Rx.Observable.timer(0, 5000),
   Rx.Observable.from(Object.entries(obj)),
   (timer,val)=>val
)
.subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```